# Drop-down menu not enabled in IE11 non-compatibility mode

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

We are migrating the app to IE11 from IE8. Everything in the app works perfectly well, but for the fact that the drop-down menus in the app don't show up. If you hover over it, it does show a "hand" and on clicking then, it does drop down.

So basically the only thing that's missing is the fact that the little arrow for drop-down menus dont' show up, although it functions perfectly well.

Any idea how to correct this and get the drop-down menus to show up like in regular IE8?

PS: I cannot be using the compatibility mode. I would need to use the regular, non-compatibility mode for IE11. Also, it works perfectly well in compatibility mode.

Here is the code bit for the input type: 
`<input  id="retrieveReports_filterReports" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" value="" autoComplete="false"
                                        style="width: 350px;" highlightMatch="all" queryExpr="*&#36;{0}*" invalidMessage="Please enter a report name, keyword or key."
                                        name="auto_complete" store="reportStore" onchange = "getMatchingReports(this.value.index)"/>`

It seems to be using dojo's dijit library.

I am not able to upload pictures to be able to demonstrate this. But hope this helps!

Comment: It would help if you posted some of the code you're using.  Try isolating things down to a minimal demonstration.

Comment: Hi Lance, I've updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to correct a CSS file to change the visibility to inline or visible [both work] for the drop down arrow. 
Another way would probably have been if the Dojo version was upgraded, but that was not in scope.